# Speed up glacial sql statement?

Tags: sql, indexing, case, sybase

I am writing a report that performs a join on three tables.

PartitionCode has about 127 rows.
AcctListLocal has about 17,000 rows.
TrialBal has, ahem, 70,000,000+ rows

The DBMS is Sybase 15

This is taking forever to execute - over 45 mins.  It is a development server used by other teams, but still I don't think it's execution time will be acceptable.

All tables have composite PKs -

```
AcctListLocal (PK and Index)
=============
acct_local
lv1
lv2
entity_code

PartitonCode (PK and Index)
============
entity_code
partition_code

TrialBal (PK + 3 indexes)
========
**PK/Index 1**
ac_cp
ac_gl
ac_gl_ctrl
ac_taps
code
ccy
id
company
co_ta
cc
entity_code
partition_code
pl_date
pro_num
src

**Index 2**
pl_date
entity_code
pro_num

**Index 3**
pl_date
entity_code
company
ac_gl

**Index 4**
pnl_date
entity_code
partition_code
```

Is part of my problem I'm joining on incomplete indexes - that is, all the indexes are 'composite' fields, but I'm only matching on a couple of them?  do i create indexes on
    Trial balance consisting on entity_code and partition_code to match to PartitonCode 
and
    AccListLocal on entity_code and ac_gl to match the lookup to RegalTrialBal

Or are the CASE statements just horrendous?

SQL is below:

```
INSERT INTO #VolumesAndValues 
    SELECT 
        ahl.lv1 AS base, 
        ahl.lv2 AS ap, 
        ahl.lv3 AS mc1, 
        sum(tb.us) as total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 = 'MA' THEN tb.us ELSE 0 END) AS base,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 = 'AJ' THEN tb.us ELSE 0 END) AS batch,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 in('ADCG','ADIG') AND 1=1 THEN rtb.us ELSE 0 END) AS net,                    
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 = 'FR' THEN tb.us ELSE 0 END) AS fr,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 = 'PA' THEN tb.us ELSE 0 END) AS pa,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 = 'RE' THEN tb.us ELSE 0 END) AS re,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 = 'OF' THEN tb.us ELSE 0 END) AS of,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pc.partition_lv2 = 'PR' THEN tb.us ELSE 0 END) AS pr,
        '1 Table Data' as rowType
FROM TrialBal tb 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AcctListLocal al ON tb.entity_code = al.entity_code
        and tb.ac_gl_c = al.ac_local
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PartitionCode pc ON pc.partition_code = tb.partition_code
GROUP BY al.lv1, al.lv2, al.lv3
```

Comment: You are doing a `left join` on a table that has 70 million rows.  All the data needs to be processed, so the query is going to take a long time.

Comment: I will replace the outer with inner join, will see what that does to the execution time - though each TrialBal row should map to an entry in the other two tables.

Comment: So, 17,000 rows in one table (`AcctListLocal`) map to 70,000,000 rows in `TrialBal`.  That is 4,000+ rows for each "AcctListLocal" record.  That seems like a lot to me.  I'm further surprised that in such a data structure, you don't have a single column primary key linking the tables.

Comment: Sadly not my schema (no power to make any amendments), just dealing with the fall out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data structure allows it, perform your aggregation BEFORE all of your case statements, for example:

```
INSERT INTO #VolumesAndValues 
SELECT
    base
    ,ap
    ,mc1
    ,plv2
    ,sum(subtotal) as total
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 = 'MA' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS base
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 = 'AJ' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS batch
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 in('ADCG','ADIG') AND 1=1 THEN othersubtotal ELSE 0 END) AS net                    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 = 'FR' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS fr
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 = 'PA' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS pa
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 = 'RE' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS re
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 = 'OF' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS of
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN plv2 = 'PR' THEN subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS pr
    ,'1 Table Data' as rowType
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ahl.lv1 AS base 
        ,ahl.lv2 AS ap
        ,ahl.lv3 AS mc1 
        ,pc.partition_lv2 as plv2
        ,sum(tb.us) as subtotal
        ,sum(rtb.us) as othersubtotal
    FROM TrialBal tb 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AcctListLocal al ON tb.entity_code = al.entity_code
        and tb.ac_gl_c = al.ac_local
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PartitionCode pc ON pc.partition_code = tb.partition_code
    GROUP BY 
            al.lv1
            ,al.lv2
            ,al.lv3 
            ,pc.partition_lv2
) subq
GROUP BY
    base
    ,ap
    ,mc1
    ,plv2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the difference between the above and the inner join from Gordon Linoff was negligible.

Comment: Is it just the volume of data I'm dealing with?  Only other option is potentially sending it to KDB, which gives me the heebie-jeebies...

Comment: Try doing both my solution and the inner join, Gordon's and my suggestions both address different performance sinks.  In my case, I minimized the number of comparison operations needed to be performed by your query.

Comment: Hmmm, an improvement - down from 36 mins to a not insignificant 22!

Comment: Not bad.  I can't think of any more obvious query fixes right now, but you might look into the index situation that others have commented on.  Looking at the schema you posted, I don't think your query is able to use indexes 2-4 at all.  If you're not able to add or request indexes, would your project requirements allow you to add a parameter to filter on date range?  If you can use PL_Date, I think you'd see a massive performance boost.

Comment: Can't use pl_date.  Will create the 2 indexes and see what boost that gives me.  I'd also like to know if this size of data is likely in PRD, though I can only get a vague answer on this.